# Web Forms Model Binding Checkboxlist

Tags: asp.net, webforms, model-binding

I'm relatively new to .net development, so I'm not sure if I'm approaching this correctly.

Basically, I have a model called Games. A game can belong to multiple platforms, such as Windows. Simple many to many relationship. I defined it in my code-first model as follows:

```
public virtual ICollection<Platform> Platforms { get; set; }
```

When adding a new game to the site, a user has to choose from a Checkboxlist of all available platforms. I didn't have any trouble populating the list with all the entries in the Platforms table. This is all contained inside of a FormView control, with an InsertMethod of InsertItem.

However, I'm not sure where to go from there. How do I retrieve the postback value of the checkboxes in the context of InsertItem? How would I express the checked values in the checkbox as instances of the Platform model, as well as validating that at least one platform was checked.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show the code of how you populate the checkbox list. It comes to my mind that probably a Grid would be more suitable?